# Ручной запуск вентилятора в linux

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

Мне нужно вручную запустить вентилятор. У меня получается сделать это с помощью команд:

`sudo pwmconfig && sudo yes`

`sudo echo 255 >> /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1`

Но он запускается, и тут же выключается. Видимо, автоматический контроль вентиляторов видит температуру процессора и останавливает его. Можно, конечно, запихнуть эту комаду в while [1] do... но это будет как-то неправильно. Как остановить службу динамичной регулировки мощности?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/sysfs-interface проверьте состояние `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1_enable`

Comment: в биосе ещё отключите ``cool`n`quiet``

Comment: Файла ...pwm1_enable нет

Comment: Это очень странно. И кстати странно, что у вас путь sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1 у меня например там еще device есть sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/device/pwm1 и там есть pwm1_enable А скоростью я при этом управляю записью вообще в fanX_input

Comment: Если hwmon?/pwm? нет, поможет копание в регистрах EC. https://habr.com/ru/post/189616/

Comment: Метод представленный на сайте по ссылке сейчас попробую. Пока, по выводу команды sensors понял, что вентилятор ещё можно контролировать через файл /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1. А в папке power, находящийся рядом с этим файлом, есть интересная настройка control. Там значение auto. Когда пытаюсь присвоить manual, пишет недопустимый аргумент, а когда auto - всё хорошо. Какое слово можно попробовать туда записать?